# build android using gradle and cpp-libraray

Tags: gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I want to build android libs (.a and .so) using gradle using cpp-library plugin.
I search a bit and checked ndk samples. at least ndk samples are using cmake as backend and old model which seems to be removed in gradle 8.0

does have someone experience? are there any ways to implement it?